# Kafka Streams with state stores - Reprocessing of messages on app restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have the following topology with two transformers, and each transformer uses persistent state store:

```
kStreamBuilder.stream(inboundTopicName)
    .transform(() -> new FirstTransformer(FIRST_STATE_STORE), FIRST_STATE_STORE)
    .map((key, value) -> ...)
    .transform(() -> new SecondTransformer(SECOND_STATE_STORE), SECOND_STATE_STORE)
    .to(outboundTopicName);
```

and Kafka settings has `auto.offset.reset: latest`. After app was launched, I see two internal compacted topics were creates (and it's expected): `appId_inbound_firstStateStore-changelog` and `appId_inbound_secondStateStore-changelog`

Our app was down for two days, and after we started app again, messages were reprocessed from the beginning for specific partition (but we have multiple partitions). 
I know that committed offsets are stored during ~ 1 day for kafka brokers prior to version 2, so our offsets should be cleaned up by retention. **But why messages were reprocessed from beginning if we use `auto.offset.reset: latest`?** Maybe it's somehow relate to stateful operations or changelog internal topics.

I see the following logs (most of them are duplicated multiple times):

```
StoreChangelogReader Restoring task 0_55's state store firstStateStore from beginning of the changelog
Fetcher [Consumer clientId=xxx-restore-consumer, groupId=] Resetting offset for partition xxx-55 to offset 0
ConsumerCoordinator Setting newly assigned partitions
ConsumerCoordinator Revoking previously assigned partitions
StreamsPartitionAssignor Assigned tasks to clients
AbstractCoordinator Successfully joined group with generation
StreamThread partition revocation took xxx ms
Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
AbstractCoordinator (Re-)joining group
Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
AbstractCoordinator Group coordinator xxx:9092 (id: xxx rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=xxx-restore-consumer, groupId=] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

Kafka broker version `0.11.0.2`; Kafka Streams version `2.1.0`

Comment: Not sure. Can you check the client logs? It might shed some light. Resetting is logged.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I added logs, could you please look on it. what exactly should I find in logs? I see for all partitions: `Resetting offset for partition xxx-55 to offset 0` for clientId `xxx-restore-consumer`

Comment: Not sure atm. Different thought: Did you set the reset policy for your Streams app explicitly? Asking because Consumer default is "latest" while KafkaStreams default is "earliest".

Comment: yes, we explicitly set `auto.offset.reset: latest` for KafkaStreams configs

Comment: And consumer/streams config also logs this value on startup? -- Running out of ideas. I offset zero would be committed, it could also explain what you see. Can you verify if any offset is committed?

Comment: I see from graphana Kafka lag, that we commit offsets (lag was decreased when app works). from logs I see: `ConsumerConfig values: auto.offset.reset = latest` for client.id = xxx-consumer; and `ConsumerConfig values: auto.offset.reset = none` for client.id = xxx-restore-consumer

Comment: For restore consumer, it's expected. You cannot overwrite it, but Kafka Streams handles it internally. If you commit offsets, Kafka Streams will pick up those on startup. Could it be, that the committed offset was zero? If not, maybe there is a bug if offsets expire... Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks. I saw that kafka lag was changing and near to zero before app was shutdown for several days, so offset was committed and for sure non-zero. anyway, I will try to reproduce issue, and if will have luck for that - will let you know.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax we also found that exactly one day after service has been shut down kafka lag has been increased significantly by the number of messages that were in the topic on the moment of service shut down. Looks like offset has been set to the beginning of the topic. How could such happens?

Comment: @AlexKamornikov I am not sure atm how this could have happened. The consumer make the decision where to read from. (1) it tried to receive committed offsets from the broker (2) if provided offsets are invalid (ie, topic as truncated) or not offsets are found, `auto.offset.reset` is applied. The decision the consumer makes, and why, are logged in DEBUG or TRACE level. This might shed some light.