# Could Kafka set the consumer group offset to the beginning of the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We faced next issue:
There is a service(kafka-streams app) that was shut down for ~4 days. After turning it on it had started to consume already consumer messages that was processed couple of days before service was shut down. Service has `auto.offset.reset: latest` which should prevent such behavior.

We found that kafka lag increased significantly(by ~30 millions of messages) exactly one day after service has been shut down.

Maybe I'm wrong but looks like the offset has been moved to the beginning of the topic - that's why `latest` didn't work. How such could have happened?

Could it be connected to kafka-streams somehow(we have couple of transformers with persistent state stores)?

Comment: Seems to similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263568/kafka-streams-with-state-stores-reprocessing-of-messages-on-app-restart, but without answer

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem. Asked in that thread